# Comparing Two 2-D tuples with numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, tuples

I have two nested tuples named **coord** and **coord2** and **I want to see if one set of coordinates in the first tuple match another in the other tuple regardless of the index.**

For example,

```
coord[0][1] = 127,
coord[0][2] = 128,
coord[0] = 127,128,129....
coord[1][0] = 302,
coord[1] = 302,303,304 ....
```

Right now I can see if each index matches the other tuple's index exactly, but not whether one set exists in the other. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(60):
if (coord[0][i]) == (coord2[0][i]) and (coord[1][i]) == (coord2[1][i]):
    print(coord[0][i])
    print(coord[1][i])
    count += 1
    total += 1
else:
    total += 1
```

How should I go about doing this? I am pretty new to using numpy arrays in python

I have written some new code like so,

```
for i in range(60):
    if coord2[0][i] and coord2[1][i] in coord:
        count += 1
        total += 1
    else:
        total += 1
```

In my mind this should tell me if any set of coordinates in the second tuple is in the first one. But I am running into an error saying, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Let's make sure the terminology is right.  `2-D tuple` is not clear.  A tuple, like a list can contain number or other lists/tuples.  I prefer the term 'nested list/tuple` rather than 2d.  `numpy` arrays though may be 2d.  And an array made from nested tuples may end up being 2d.  Anyways, at the moment you are indexing `coord` as a nested tuple (or list). Does that work for you?  What, if anything, is wrong?

Comment: So I just want to know if any coordinates in the second tuple, coord2, is in the first tuple coord. I have written some new code that I believe should accomplish this, but I am running into an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to know if any of the coordinates of one matrix exist in another then this is one way of doing it.

```
import itertools
import numpy
```

First let's get all possible index combinations for the matrices

```
idx = tuple(e for e in itertools.product(range(len(coord)), repeat=2))

((0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 0),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 3))
```

Then let's compare the two indexed matrices and see if any of the points exist in the other

```
coord = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

coord1 = np.random.randint(1, size=(4,4))

np.equal([coord[_idx] for _idx in idx],[coord1[_idx] for _idx in idx])

array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Edit: If you simply want the number of occurrences then it becomes this

```
np.sum(np.equal([coord[_idx] for _idx in idx],[coord1[_idx] for _idx in idx]))

>>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured it out.

```
for i in range(200):
    if (coord2[0][i]) in coord[0] and coord2[1][i] in coord[1]:
        count += 1
        total += 1
    else:
        total += 1
```